# Ler uma imagem em SQL Server para uma picturebox em C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tenho ByteArrays de imagens em uma base de dados no MySQL Server e pretendo lê-las e depois disso converter o ByteArray para uma imagem que possa ser disposta numa picturebox.
Já tentei usar outros métodos incluindo uma dll, no entanto existiam sempre erros e achei que desta forma estaria mais simples.

De momento o código que tenho é este:

```
StringBuilder str5Sql = new StringBuilder();
        str5Sql.Append("SELECT TOP 1000 MOVIMENTO_MATERIAL.IMAGEM FROM MOVIMENTO_MATERIAL INNER JOIN MATERIAL ON  MOVIMENTO_MATERIAL.ID_MATERIAL = MATERIAL.ID WHERE MOVIMENTO_MATERIAL.ID IN (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM MOVIMENTO_MATERIAL WHERE MOVIMENTO_MATERIAL.ID_MATERIAL = @wantedcell ORDER BY ID DESC )");
        i = 0;
        using (SqlConnection sql5Conn = new SqlConnection(strConexao))
        using (SqlCommand sql5Cmd = new SqlCommand(str5Sql.ToString(), sql5Conn))
        {

            sql5Conn.Open();
            sql5Cmd.Parameters.Add("@wantedcell", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = this.wantedcell;

            using (SqlDataReader dr5 = sql5Cmd.ExecuteReader())

                while (dr5.Read())
                {

                    byte[] byteimagem = BitConverter.GetBytes(dr5[0]);
                    Image imagem_ultima = Diversos.ByteArrayToImage(byteimagem);
                    pictureBox2.Image = imagem_ultima;



                    //Incrementa uma interação
                    i++;
                }
        }
```

Na linha onde tento guardar os dados em uma variável ByteArray dou-me de caras com o seguinte erro:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'bool'
```

Alguém sabe alguma maneira de deixar isto a funcionar corretamente?

Comment: Em qual linha exatamente o erro ocorre? Não parece que está relacionado com a imagem.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow na linha 'byte[] byteimagem = BitConverter.GetBytes(dr5[0]);'

Comment: E por que a cada linha você vai trocando a imagem do mesmo componente na tela? o que você espera realizar com isso?

Comment: usa `byte[] byteimagem =  (byte[])dr5[0]`

Comment: @RovannLinhalis acabei de testar isso e funcionou, muito obrigado :)